# Check checkbox with data from another database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I've been twisting my head for days without getting what I want, so I'm writing here hoping to get some help.
I have two tables (actually 3, but we'll leave the last one out here).

```
TABLE 1 NAME:
pakkliste_gjenstand

COLUMNS:
id 
pakkliste_gjenstand


TABLE 2 NAME:
pakkliste_detalj

COLUMNS:
id
prosjekt_id 
pakkliste_detalj_gjenstand_id
pakkliste_detalj_gjenstand
```

In the "pakkliste_gjenstand" table there are hundres of lines with items that I can select by checkboxes, and add to the "pakkliste_detalj" table. The id-field from the "pakkliste_gjenstand"-table is stored in the "pakkliste_detalj"-table as pakkliste_detalj_gjenstand_id

Then we get to what I want, namely to run a reverse to be able to update my "pakkiste_detalj"-table.
I want to be able to loop through the entire "pakkliste_gjenstand"-table, and check off the lines that are already selected in "pakkliste_detalj"-table. I need to match the id-field in table 1 (pakkliste_gjenstand) with pakkliste_detalj_gjenstand_id in table 2 (pakkliste_detalj).

I use the following code to loop throug the "pakkliste_gjenstand"-table:

```
<?php
$do_search=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * 
                                FROM pakkliste_gjenstand 
                                ORDER BY pakkliste_gjenstand ASC");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do_search)) 
{
    $id=$row['id'];
    $produkt=$row['pakkliste_gjenstand'];
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>*<?php echo $produkt; ?>"> <?php echo $produkt; ?>
<br>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Is it possible to do something with this so that I can have the items from "pakkliste_detalj" to be checked, but still show the rest of the lines as well?

I've searched the net, and tried different codes as LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN and a lot other approaches without luck.

Could anyone help me? I don't want to use javascript ...

**UPDATE:**

Someone suggested Right Join, and I've used this code

```
<?php
$do_search=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM pakkliste_gjenstand RIGHT JOIN pakkliste_detalj ON pakkliste_gjenstand.id = pakkliste_detalj.pakkliste_detalj_gjenstand_id WHERE pakkliste_detalj.prosjekt_id = '$prosjektid' ORDER BY pakkliste_gjenstand.pakkliste_gjenstand ASC");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($do_search)) 
{
$id=$row['id'];
$produkt=$row['pakkliste_gjenstand'];
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>*<?php echo $produkt; ?>"> <?php echo $produkt; ?>
<br>
<?php 
}
?>
```

This will only provide the posts I've added to the "pakkliste_detalj"-table, but I want all posts from the "pakkliste_gjenstand"-table to display up with the checkboxes selected from according fields in "pakkliste_detalj"-table

I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're on the right track. Have a look into [RIGHT JOIN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-right-join/) and see if those examples/explanation would do what you want.